# default.auth(...).collection is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I started to get this error after editing my react.js code and i couldnt get rid of it. Checked some other pages about firebase.auth is not a function error but the answers there didnt help. Error gives at the beginninh of main.js file starting with "fire.auth..."

Exact error message:

> TypeError: _config_Fire__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.auth(...).collection is not a function

My fire.js code

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore'

const config = { /* COPY THE ACTUAL CONFIG FROM FIREBASE CONSOLE */
    my config info here ...
};
const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default fire;
```

My main.js file which gives error:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect, useRef, useContext} from 'react'
import fire from '../config/Fire';
//import { UserConsumer } from  './UserContext.js';

//import {UserContext} from '../App'


function useTimes(){
  //const user2 = useContext(UserContext.Consumer)
    const [kullanici,setTimes] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
      fire
            .auth()
            .collection('kullanici')
            .doc('gNfFy0uEsk5OvrZOfkGm')
            .onSnapshot((doc)=>{
                const newTimes = doc.data()
                setTimes(newTimes)
            })

    },[])

    return kullanici
}
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
    const savedCallback = useRef();

    // Remember the latest callback.
    useEffect(() => {
      savedCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    // Set up the interval.
    useEffect(() => {
      function tick() {
        savedCallback.current();
      }
      if (delay !== null) {
        let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
      }
    }, [delay]);
  }

const Main = () => {
  //console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    const kullanici =useTimes()
    let [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    //console.log(new Date().getTime())
    useInterval(() => {
        // Your custom logic here
        setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return(
      <div>
        <div>
        <h2>Welcome {kullanici.nick}</h2>
        <li>Silver: <span>{kullanici.silver ? count * kullanici.silver : ''}</span></li>
        <li>Copper: <span id="count">{kullanici.silver ? count * kullanici.copper : ''}</span></li>
        <li>Iron: <span id="count">{kullanici.silver ? count * kullanici.iron : ''}</span></li>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
  }


export default Main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have to import `firebase/auth` in your `fire.js` file.

And also try to import the core firebase sdk with `firebase/app`.

```
// fire.js

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth';

...
```

This will solve the error `.auth is not a function`.

And lastly, you are trying to chain `.collection()` on `auth()`. If you are trying to read data from Firestore, you have to do it this way:

```
// main.js

...

import fire from '../config/Fire';

...

fire
  .firestore()
  .collection('kullanici')

...
```

Comment: it didnt solve the problem, also my script was working before without adding /app and /auth

Comment: This can't have worked: `fire.auth().collection('kullanici')` as the Firebase Authentication object doesn't have a `collection` function. As onoya said you'll need to import Firebase correctly, and then get `collection` from `firebase.firestore()`.